# Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled when running jest test in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

Getting the error:

```
 Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled
```

When I try to run a jest test to render one of my react components. This is what I have in my jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  coverageProvider: "v8",
  "setupFiles": [
    "./jest.setup.js"
  ],
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
};
```

In babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env", {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      },
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", { "pragma":"h" }]
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
};
```

in jest.setup.js:

```
globalThis.fetch = require('node-fetch')
```

and in my package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/user-event": "13.5.0",
    ...
  },
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "jest",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.17.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.16.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1"
  }
}
```

This is the full traceback I am getting:

```
 SyntaxError: C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\peerplatform\peerplatform-fe\src\tests\userLogin.test.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (6:12):

      4 |
      5 | test('Login page renders with no errors', () => {
    > 6 |     render(<Login/>)
        |            ^
      7 | })
      8 |

    Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
    If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

I already have @babel/preset-react in the presets section of my Babel confif

**UPDATE**

I added a .babelrc file to the root of my frontend folder and added this

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

But now this gives me the error:

```
   SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

      1 | import React, { Component,useState,useEffect,useContext } from "react";
    > 2 | import secure_login from "../../assets/images/secure_login.svg"
        | ^
```